# Can you split rx into multiple variables and concatenate the evaluation

Tags: rx

I have a really useful regex for extracting DCOs:

```el
(defvar my-dco-tag-re
  (rx (: bol (zero-or-more (in blank))                     ; fresh line
         (any "RSTA") (one-or-more (in alpha "-")) "-by: " ; tag
         (one-or-more (in alpha blank "-."))               ; name
         blank
         "<" (one-or-more (not (in ">"))) ">"))            ; email
  "Regexp to match DCO style tag.")
```

However I've just recently come up with another use case which doesn't want to start on the begining of the line. Is it possible to evaluate RX variables in RX? I thought I could do this:

```el
(defvar my-bare-dco-tag-rx
  '((any "RSTA") (one-or-more (in alpha "-")) "-by: " ; tag
    (one-or-more (in alpha blank "-."))               ; name
    blank
    "<" (one-or-more (not (in ">"))) ">")             ; email
  "Regexp to match plain DCO tag")

(defvar my-dco-tag-re
  (rx (: bol (zero-or-more (in blank))  ; fresh line
         (eval my-bare-dco-tag-rx)))
  "Regexp to match DCO style tag.")
```

but it causes the evaluation to bug out. Any ideas?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Bad rx operator ‘(any \"RSTA\")’")
  error("Bad rx operator `%S'" (any "RSTA"))
  rx--translate-form(((any "RSTA") (one-or-more (in alpha "-")) "-by: " (one-or-more (in alpha blank "-.")) blank "<" (one-or-more (not (in ">"))) ">"))
  rx--translate(((any "RSTA") (one-or-more (in alpha "-")) "-by: " (one-or-more (in alpha blank "-.")) blank "<" (one-or-more (not (in ">"))) ">"))
  rx--translate-eval((my-bare-dco-tag-rx))
  rx--translate-form((eval my-bare-dco-tag-rx))
  rx--translate((eval my-bare-dco-tag-rx))
  mapcar(rx--translate (bol (zero-or-more (in blank)) (eval my-bare-dco-tag-rx)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas?

The `eval` construct in `rx` expects a single `rx` form, but you are giving it a list of `rx` forms.  Try sequencing the spliced forms instead (or adding `:` to the beginning of `my-bare-dco-tag-rx`):

```el
(defvar my-dco-tag-re
  (rx (: bol (zero-or-more (in blank))
         (eval `(: ,@my-bare-dco-tag-rx))))
  "Regexp to match DCO style tag.")

;; Or, equivalently:

(defvar my-dco-tag-re
  (rx (: bol (zero-or-more (in blank))
         (eval (cons ': my-bare-dco-tag-rx))))
  "Regexp to match DCO style tag.")
```

BTW, Emacs 27 added new macros for defining named and optionally parameterised `rx` constructs, namely `rx-define`, `rx-let`, and `rx-let-eval`; see [`(info "(elisp) Extending Rx")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extending-Rx.html).  For example:

```el
(rx-define my-bare-dco-tag
  (: (any "RSTA") (one-or-more (in alpha "-")) "-by: "
     (one-or-more (in alpha blank "-."))
     blank
     "<" (one-or-more (not (in ">"))) ">"))

(rx-define my-dco-tag
  (: bol (zero-or-more (in blank)) my-bare-dco-tag))

(rx my-bare-dco-tag)
;; => "[AR-T][[:alpha:]-]+-by: [.[:alpha:][:blank:]-]+[[:blank:]]<[^>]+>"

(rx my-dco-tag)
;; => "^[[:blank:]]*[AR-T][[:alpha:]-]+-by: [.[:alpha:][:blank:]-]+[[:blank:]]<[^>]+>"
```